Accessing environment variables in index.html file
I am trying to access some environment variables inside of the index.html file. Are the environment variables even accessible at the time the index.html builds? I have tried something along the lines of this and I am able to print out the log in the console
index.html
<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log('this is inside index.html');
</script>

But when I try to access the environment variables I am unable to do so. I have read in a few places that this is possible, but am unable to accomplish it.
.env file
VITE_MY_VAR = 'HELLO WORLD'

index.html
<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log('my env var', VITE_MY_VAR);
   <% console.log('test', process.env['VITE_MY_VAR']) %>
</script>


@Phil sorry, yes. I am using VITE. Just updated tags

Why are you trying to use a <script> tag in your HTML instead of just using a bundled JS file?

FYI if you include ; at the end of your .env values, it will be included literally. You also don't need quotes

See HTML Env Replacement...

Vite also supports replacing env variables in HTML files. Any properties in import.meta.env can be used in HTML files with a special %ENV_NAME% syntax

Note: This requires Vite v4 or later
The issue with trying to use this in a <script> tag is quoting and escaping; Vite performs no other action than direct replacement. You would need to attempt to ensure there are no unescaped quote characters in your .env values when presented as a JavaScript string literal
<script>
  console.log('my env var', `%VITE_MY_VAR%`); //  value must be quoted
                                              // as a string literal
</script>

This will be directly injected as
<script>
  console.log('my env var', `Hello World`);
</script>


Note (and I see this a lot), DO NOT terminate your .env values with a semi-colon (;). If you do, this will be included literally in the value.
You also do not need quotes and if you do, they will be stripped out anyway.
I'd recommend keeping it as simple as possible
VITE_MY_VAR=Hello World


so in theory if the value of VITE_MY_VAR is 'Hello World'. Then using what you mentioned above %VITE_MY_VAR% should print out the expected value?

Could very well be doing something wrong, but this is what is printing out to the console %VITE_MY_VAR%. This is how I am writing the log console.log('my env var', %VITE_MY_VAR%);

It works for me using Vite ^4.4.5. I added VITE_MY_VAR=Hello World to .env, added the <script> block to index.html, ran yarn dev and opened the http://localhost:5173 page. Make sure you're editing the index.html that's in your project root

hmmm I am on "vite": "^3.1.6"

Vite v3 does not have the HTML replacement feature. It's also almost 3 years old

I am wondering if react-helmet would be a better idea than upgrading vite

You didn't answer my question about why you even need this. It honestly doesn't make sense to me when you can just use import.meta.env.VITE_MY_VAR in one of your bundled JS files / React components

I am trying to add a javascript snippet that allows me to plug into an SDK, but the values in the snippet will be dynamic based on env

Upgrading to 4.4.5 did fix the issue though as described

Ah, that makes more sense than console.log() :D
